# Organising Flask app. SSL on one subdomain with shared static

Tags: python, ssl, heroku, flask

I have a Flask app that I'm building that has 3 distinct parts.

1. `www.` This is all static HTML, CSS, JS etc. I'm using Flask to build it and then using Frozen-Flask to package it into static files ready for hosting.
2. `secure.` A small amount of the site contains secure content that I want behind HTTPS. This part will live on Heroku (or similar). It needs to have a similar look and feel to `www.` so I would like to share the static content between them.
3. `api.` This lives on Heroku but does not need to be secured. At the moment it provides a cached Twitter stream for the company's Twitter account.

How should I best organise these things? I had `api.` and `www.` in separate projects completely but when I started to build `secure.` I thought that I should combine them. If I have a single project then I can easily use `url_for` to build my URLs. Development is easier because I can run everything in one. Also, it feels like it should be easier to share static content. I've tried but I've run into some headaches and I don't know if this is the right way to do things. I got the subdomains working using blueprints but my static files aren't loaded because (I think) I need to tell the Blueprint where its static files are, but of course I want them to share. I've started down this rabbit hole but I've stopped to ask here because I don't want to over-complicate things.

If I keep these parts in separate projects then deployment is really easy. Handling HTTPS for the `secure.` parts is simple and I like the cleanliness of having them be distinct. How would I get them to share static content? Copy the static files from one repo to another? I can't link the non-SSL versions from the SSL project and it seems wasteful to link the SSL static content in the non-SSL. Is there anyway I can use the `url_for` method to generate URLs for applications outside of the current one? e.g. Can I get the `www.` project to build the URL for a page inside the `secure.` if they're in distinct projects.

That's a huge wall of text, I'll stop there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Perhaps. It's about how to organise code and how to connect distinct parts. Server fault wouldn't be right but maybe Webmaster, I don't know, I've not used it.